# Introjs on load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onload, intro.js

I'm trying to implement an introduction tour for my site and came across [Introjs](https://introjs.com/).

All the examples show the tour launching upon button click, but I'm wondering if there's a way to launch the tour once the page loads without a button click.  Additionally, is it possible to have it launch only for the first time visiting?

I'm using `angularjs` to build my site, but am very much a **novice**.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `introJs().start()` on document ready event.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
  introJs().start();
});
```

The example on https://introjs.com/docs/getting-started/start uses the function call `introJs().start()`

You only have to call the function whether on button click or document ready event.

Coming to the second part of your question, the easiest solution would be to use `localStorage`.

Something like this, should do the trick.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 

    var hadTour = localStorage.getItem('hadTour');

    if(!hadTour){
            introJs().oncomplete(function() {
            localStorage.setItem('hadTour', true);
            }).onexit(function(){
            localStorage.setItem('hadTour', true);
            }).start();
    }

});
```

Comment: thanks Faisal!  will test it out and get back to you, much appreciated!

Comment: Sure, no problem :)

Comment: hey @faisal, do you know if Introjs Hints has be started from a button click?  I looked at the documentation and the tour is started by .start(), but I don't see the same thing for Hints.  Is it possible to start Hints onload as well?

Comment: Yeah. Simply add "data-hint" attribute to the element and in javascript where we have .start() stack .addHints() on  it  like this .start().addHints();

Comment: Method stacking is only required if you want to start the tour and add hints at the same time, but if you only want to add hints you can remove .start();